# How to pass props from previous screen to next screen through static navigationOptions?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-redux, react-navigation

I have this transition of screens:

> A -> B -> C

Now on B, I have this `static navigationOptions`:

```
class ScreenB extends Component {

    static navigationOptions = ({navigation}) => ({

    /* works fine to display props here -> */   title: navigation.state.params.MyString, // works fine for display
                                                headerLeft: <Button title="<" onPress={() => navigation.goBack()} />, 
    /* does not work to pass it here -> */      headerRight: <Button title="+" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ScreenC', {navigation.state.params.MyString})} />
                                } );

    // ...
}
```

I receive `MyString` from `A`, and display it fine in `B`. But I would like to pass it to `C` on `headerRight` button click. A syntax error on its definition says:

> *Unexpected token, expected ,*

What would be the issue? Thanks

Comment: I'm assuming you're using some sort of packing? I don't see any obvious syntax errors. The last time I had one of these frustrating experiences, wrapping the component in parenthesis fixed it, for some reason. headerLeft: (<Button ... />), .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this line:

```
headerRight: <Button title="+" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ScreenC', {navigation.state.params.MyString})} />
```

For:

```
headerRight: <Button title="+" onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ScreenC', {title:navigation.state.params.MyString})} />
```

You are missing the key.